# How does add_index in Rails work with "unique:true" for 2 parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

How is the unique true applied to 2 ids?

```
add_index :table_name, [:some_id, :another_id], unique: true, algorithm: :concurrently
```

Comment: Its a composite index, that is, the combination of the two columns must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

It means in your `table_name`, there is only one row with unique value of `some_id` and `another_id` with order of index, example:

```
id, some_id, another_id
1, 11, 22
2, 11, 33
3, 22, 11
```

then database will not allow you to insert a new row with `some_id = 11` and `another_id = 22`

The order of `[:some_id, :another_id]` is important because database will decide to use index based on that order, for examples:

This queries will use index:

```
select * from table_name where some_id = '11'
select * from table_name where some_id = '11' AND another_id = '22'
```

This query will not use index:

```
select * from table_name where another_id = '22'
```